# Susy prefix, suffix, pad wrong output with gutter-position inside

Tags: css, susy, susy-sass, libsass

I don't know what is happening with the output of `prefix`, `suffix` and `pad` when using `gutter-position: inside`. For example:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    gutter-position: inside,
    global-box-sizing: border-box
);

body {
    @include pad(gutter());
}
```

The output is:

```
body {
  padding-left: 1.6666666667%;
  padding-right: 1.6666666667%;
}
```

And comparing with the `squish` mixin:

```
body {
  margin-left: 0.8333333333%;
  margin-right: 0.8333333333%;
}
```

The desired output is `0.8333333333%` but `pad` still doesn't "split".

And they both together - locally should output the same value, but it doesn't:

```
body {
    @include pad(gutter());
    @include squish(gutter());
}
```

The output:

```
body {
  padding-left: 1.6666666667%;
  padding-right: 1.6666666667%;
  margin-left: 0.8333333333%;
  margin-right: 0.8333333333%;
}
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These mixins are not meant for applying gutters (use `@include gutter()` or `@include gutter(split)` for that) — they are meant for *additional* margins and padding. In order to do that properly in most cases, they try maintain existing gutters *in addition to* any padding/margins you ask for. In your case, the gutters are being added to `pad` and not `squish` because your `gutter-position` is `inside`. You've asked for a gutter width, `pad` adds a gutter width, and you end up with double. If you want to use either of those mixins without having gutter widths included, use the `no-gutters` keyword (`pad($width no-gutters)`).